# representation of bivariate normal distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $(X,Y)$ have bivariate normal distribution with zero means, $a^2$ and $b^2$ variances and correlation $p$. Today I came across interesting representation of it.

Let $U,V$ be independent random variables with standard normal distribution then:

$$X=apU+a \sqrt{1-p^2}V, Y=bU$$

and we can work with this representation and it is easier to prove some facts with it.

Why can we use this representation? I know that the distributions matches but how we know these are the same functions, matches on every input from sample space? Maybe we don't need that? Can you explain this to me?

Comment: Yes, you don't need that. More accurately, this representation means $(X, Y) \color{red}{\overset{d}{=}} (apU + a\sqrt{1 - p^2}V, bU)$, where $U, V$ i.i.d. $N(0, 1)$.  It is that they share the same joint distribution that matters in statistical inference.